# const reference to the ostream class object

Tags: c++

I have written friend function to overload the << operator to display the detail about the object of my user defined class Time

I accidentally used const reference to the `ostream` class and it shows error  saying:

> error: no match for operator<<.....

Class declaration of friend function is shown below:

```
friend  void operator<<(const std::ostream & os,  const Time & t);
```

but when I use:

```
friend  void operator<<(std::ostream & os,  const Time & t);
```

Eliminating const from the code it works fine.
 Why it is that const make an error?
I think const just tells that we are not modifying object

Function definition of not working code is:

```
 void operator<<( const std::ostream & os,const Time & t)
     {
        os  << t.hours  << "  hours and " << t.minutes << " minutes "<<std::endl;
     }
```

Please help me clear this doubt
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your operator is wrong in another way as well: The overloaded "input" and "output" operators should return a reference to the stream as well. Otherwise you can't chain your output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why it is that const make an error?

Because inside of the `operator<<` function, you *do modify* the `std::ostream` object. This line

```
os  << t.hours  << "  hours and " << t.minutes << " minutes "<<std::endl;
```

writes data to the stream, so it cannot be `const`. Put more generally, when an object is declared `const` you can only invoke its member functions that are also `const`-qualified, as well as pass it to other functions that accept it by value of by `const`-qualified reference.

Answer (score 2):

In ***o***stream the **o** stands for *output*, that pretty much excludes `const`, since you write stuff into that output stream object, that by definition means the stream can't be a constant.

And also, don't forget to return the std::ostream reference from the operator, so you'll have the following: `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & os,const Time & t)`